# Typeorm: When i restart server, drop BLOB column from database

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I use Node Js with Typeorm and Mysql.

When i restart the server the BLOB img disappear from database, because the the server always drop the column ¿How can avoid this?

The drop:

```
query: ALTER TABLE `products_images` DROP COLUMN `img`
query: ALTER TABLE `products_images` ADD `img` blob NULL
```

Example of my code:

```
@Entity('products_images')
export class ProductsImages extends Base {

    @Column("blob", { nullable: true })
    img: Buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can made change in ormconfig.json file "synchronize" : false
and serve again
might be your problem is solved
its work for me

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
    "database": "money",
    "synchronize": false,
    "logging": true,
    "entities": ["dist/entity/**/*.js"],
    "migrations": ["dist/migration/**/*.js"],
    "subscribers": ["dist/subscriber/**/*.js"],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "./src/entity",
        "migrationsDir": "./src/migration",
        "subscribersDir": "./src/subscriber"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `dist` folder in your project and rerun the app.

This helps me.

Comment: Why would this work?